# IlMerge Silverlight Class Library with Custom Controls

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, custom-controls

I am trying to merge all the assemblies of an class library in a single .dll file.

I can merge all the assemblies using the Ilmerge but is that when I use the merged dll in a Silverlight application I am having trouble when a template is apply to my control and binding problems if I use a control that inherits with UserControl.

is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you merging the assemblies?  Whats wrong with including each individually in the xap?

Comment: I am trying to merge all the assemblies to make my Silverlight class library easier to use in different projects otherwise I need to add a lot of references to my projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the initial dlls are built the Xaml in the project is added as a resource in the dll.  The code generated to load this xaml will look something like this:-

```
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/SilverlightLibrary1;component/MyControl.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
```

Note how the name of the dll forms part of the Uri need to fetch the xaml.  I doubt IlMerge is able to spot that and fix it up.  Hence once merged the Uris cannot be found.

A resolution for this is probably uglier than multiple references or simply creating another project that links all the code files involved.